# What is best practice for reading all bytes from tcp socket in windows phone?

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-phone

Windows Phone SDK does not have NetworkStream and all operations for communicating with servers should be asynchronously.

So in normal .net application I can use something like that^

```
var stream = socket.GetStream();
while ((read = stream.Read (buffer, offset, size)) != 0) 
{
// bufferize it
}

//stream ended and we can parse all bytes.
```

In Windows Phone I can use only like that:

```
var args = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
            args.SetBuffer(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
args.Completed += (sender, eventArgs) =>
            {
// more code here, checking LastOperation, Errors, etc.
...
///
                var gotBuffer = eventArgs.Buffer; // our responce bytes

            };
```

So, how I can determine that message from server has more than bufferSize bytes count and read all of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found some workaround:

In github I found project "SuperSocket" with Windows Phone supporting and implementation of NetworkStream (https://github.com/kerryjiang/SuperSocket.ClientEngine/blob/master/Core/NetworkStream.cs)

But for our purpose with need some changes in it, because this code contains blocking thread reading using ManualResetEvent:

```
    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
       var resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
       var result = BeginRead(buffer, offset, count, OnComplete, resetEvent);

       resetEvent.WaitOne();
       return EndRead(result);
    }
```

And it will be a problem, because resetEvent.Set() will be calling only when socket read some data, but if no data available from server but connection is still established - socket does not notify.

So we need set "timeout" for read operation. It's probably bad option because ALL message will be delayed with this timeout:

```
public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            var resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            var result = BeginRead(buffer, offset, count, OnComplete, resetEvent);

            var res = resetEvent.WaitOne(_readTimeout); // for example 100 ms
            if (res)
                return EndRead(result);
            else
            {
                m_ReceiveEventArgs.Dispose();
                m_ReceiveEventArgs = null;
                return EndRead(new StreamAsyncResult(new SocketAsyncEventArgs(), OnComplete));
            }
        }
```

If anyone knows a better way - feel free to post answer!

Comment: What is version of your WP. With WP8 you can use *async/await* which can make your life easier.

Comment: async/await I can use in WP7 too =) 
BTW, version is WP7 and WP8.

Comment: It's better to add BackBuffer to this solution, it give chance to not wait resetEvent.WaitOne(_readTimeout);